# Pattern matching in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a string which contain full name if employee. Now I want it to compare with a String value. If more than three characters are matching then it should display all the records matching it.

```
String name1 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv";
EditText editText = findVewById(R.id.eText);
String name2 = ediText.getText().toString();

if (name2.equalsIgnoreCase(name1))
{
    //do something
}
```

The problem is here it go into if loop if it matches the full pattern ,I want to check for if the name2 matches the first three characters and more than three and all characters  entered by the user it should go into the if condition. Is there any way to do this.

Comment: Your question is vague. Please clarify. Which loop are you referring to?

Comment: If you're trying to inspect the first n letters of a string, you can use the startsWith method [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if (name2.substring(0,3).equalsIgnoreCase(name1) || (name1.lenght > 3 && name2.contains(name1)) || name2.equalsIgnoreCase(name1)) 
{
    //do something
}
```

- First condition is for looking first 3 character matching;

`name2.substring(0,3).equalsIgnoreCase(name1)`

- Second condition is for looking matcing more than 3 characters;

`(name1.lenght > 3 && name2.contains(name1))`

- Third condition is for complete match;

`name2.equalsIgnoreCase(name1)`

Comment: Not Working....I want to match if name2 contain first 3 character and more than 3 characters similar to name1...

Comment: Can you give some examples to fits this condition ? Question could be more clear in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use Regex? http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

If you are using it with list then you should look at Filter interface. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/